# Inconsistent originalStartTimeZone for All Day Events

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am noticing inconsistencies in how the event api returns the `originalStartTimeZone` and `originalStartTime` for events that are all day vs a normal event.

Using `GET /me/calendar/events/{id}` from the Graph API:

**All Day Event**

```
{
  "isAllDay" => true,
  "originalStartTimeZone" => "UTC",
  "originalStart" => "2020-12-25T08:00:00Z",
  "start" => {
    "dateTime" => "2020-12-25T00:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone" => "UTC",
  },
  "end" => {
    "dateTime" => "2020-12-26T00:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone" => "UTC",
  },
}
```

**Occurrence beginning at Midnight PST**

```
{
  "isAllDay" => false,
  "originalStartTimeZone" => "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)",
  "originalStart" => "2020-12-25T08:00:00Z",
  "start" => {
    "dateTime" => "2020-12-25T08:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone" => "UTC"
  },
  "end" => {
    "dateTime" => "2020-12-25T08:30:00.0000000",
    "timeZone" => "UTC"
  },
}
```

[According to the event docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0):

> [originalStart is] The Timestamp type represents date and time information using ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time. For example, midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2014 would look like this: '2014-01-01T00:00:00Z'

> [originalStartTimeZone is] The start time zone that was set when the event was created. A value of tzone://Microsoft/Custom indicates that a legacy custom time zone was set in desktop Outlook.

We need to use the originalStart because it remains consistent as a user makes changes to an event. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to use the `originalStart` and `originalTimeZone` for an all day event to infer that it begins at midnight locally (or even UTC).

I am ok with the answer maybe being "msft always uses UTC for all day events" but that would make the `originalStart` an incorrect value, especially since it is different from the `start['dateTime']`

Comment: Based on my analysis with Graph API/Calendar, when you send a meeting request to an attendee in a different time zone, the meeting item is displayed at the respective local times on each person's calendar, but saved in UTC. For example, a meeting organizer in the United States Pacific time zone sends a meeting request for 2:00 P.M. Pacific time to an attendee in the United States Mountain time zone. The attendee sees the meeting as starting at 3:00 P.M. Mountain time. In both cases, the meeting is saved as starting at the same UTC time of 10:00 P.M.

Comment: You're seeing it return in UTC because that's the default way the API returns date/time. You can change it to another time zone using the following header, which may help you moving forward: Prefer: outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe i phrased my problem poorly. The All Day event has the `originalStartTimeZone = UTC` but the `originalStart =  2020-12-25T08:00:00Z`. By definition, the originalStart is _always_ in UTC format. So this is saying the all day event starts at 8UTC, not midnight UTC. Compare that to the `start.dateTime` which does supply the correct timestamp as utc midnight. I am expecting for an an All Day Event that the `originalStart = 2020-12-25T00:00:00Z` OR that the originalStartTimeZone be PST, so that the originalStart reflects the same timestamp as `start.dateTime`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. In the samelines, I remember a [related thread discussed in Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2804).

Comment: That is the exact same situation described in my question, thank you. I read it a few times and i still cant come to a satisfying answer.  It seems that the issue was closed due to inactivity by the OP. How can an all day event have an `originalStart = 20201225T08:00:00Z` but a `start.dateTime = 20201225T00:00:00Z`? Thank you for your help, i asked this question to hopefully catch the graph dev teams eye, since they do not seem to accept new issues on github. Based on the issue supplied above, there does not seem to be an answer or a willingness to change the inconsistency.

Comment: Yes i thought the same after your last detailed reply. Glad that the above documentation helped/provided some insights. Still if you believe this is an issue, then consider checking with Microsoft Support, discuss about the above. Let us know how it goes. Cheers!!